# Having issues with a shell command in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently studying Python. In my course I have got to reading files. My tutor is showing me the following syntax....

```
!cat data_file/sample.txt
```

When he executes this command on screen it lets him view the text contents of the file.

When I execute the code it gives me an error of cat not recognized as a valid shell command in Python.

I have read through as much Python documentation as I can and have come up with nothing!

Can anyone please help??

Comment: `cat`  is not a python command, it is a unix/linux command. To execute in python you need to use python's system library:  `os.system('cat data_file/sample.txt') ` or variation thereof.

Comment: OK tried that and it still won't give me output of file text. Output reads 1

Answer (score 0):

Its not a python specific functionality. Please use Jupyter (Ipython).

Comment: I am working in Jupyter notebook. I do not understand why it will not execute.

Answer (score 0):

Your tutor is probably using [jupyter](https://jupyter.org/), which in turn uses [IPython](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/).

The bang (`!`) means that Ipython will execute a system shell command, like:

```
!cat data_file/sample.txt
```

In this case output the contents of a txt file. This functionality is documented [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/python-ipython-diff.html#shell-assignment)

Comment: Ok I see now. I am also using Jupyter notebook but maybe my Python version is newer than his.

Comment: If you are using Jupyter, the Python version doesn’t matter because the exclamation point at the beginning sends it to shell. It sounds more like your install is bad or you aren’t using correct working directory. Does `ls` show the directory. (Certain shell commands don’t need exclamation point and that is one.)

Comment: By the way, a useful place to test what Jupyter should do can be accessed via your browser [here](https://jupyter.org/try). You want the classic notebook interface in upper left unless you know you use JupyterLab. The sessions are temporary unless you run something every ten minutes. You can upload your files and have a virtual remote testing environment for comparing.

Comment: Hi Wayne. Thank you for you help here. I have tried cat without shell command ! and it still throws out an error. Very strange. I am literally using the same as the tutor but my Jupyter notebook refuses to accept !cat as a command. Truly baffled!

Comment: Sorry, it looks like my included question got lost among my other suggestions. Does running `ls` show you are working in the correct directory? Does executing `pwd` give you the location you expected?  Also be very careful with spaces. I don't know if you are showing us actual commands you've tried or representatives. The shell is very sensitive to spaces. The other issue may be you aren't using the same underlying system as your tutor is? In other words what kind of computer do you both have?